# How did I answer a question after a moderator had closed it?

Tags: bug, closed-questions

I answered a question 8 seconds after a moderator had closed it. I thought answers on closed questions were not allowed. Is this a bug, or is it something special with mod-deleted questions? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008750/replace-words-with-html-elements/21008831#21008831) is the question. I'm not sure if I can get the exact times of closure and answering, but I saw that when the question was under a minute old, I answered after the question had been closed

Comment: Wow that was a fast closure

Comment: Probably because it appears in the Related list to the right --> (it's the 6th item). It makes it *really easy* to find the link to the duplicate. It helps to actually look there when you post a question; if you don't catch it when you're posting, you can at least get it right afterward and delete your question.